# Авторизация через node.js passport-facebook + jwtwebtoken в rest api приложении

Tags: node.js, express, passport

Извините заранее если этот вопрос, оказыватся глупым. На данный момент авторизация реализована таким образом, при axios.post запросе с клиента, сервер отправляет токен, токен сохраняется в localstorage

```
 app.post('/login/', async (req, res) => {
            try {
                const {email, password} = req.body;
                const errors = {};
                const user = await User.findOne({email});

                if (!user) {
                    errors.email = 'Account Not Found';
                    return res.status(404).send(errors);
                }

                const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

                if (isMatch) {
                    const payload = {
                        id: user._id,
                        email: user.email,
                    };

                    jwt.sign(payload, secret, {expiresIn: 3600}, (err, token) => {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(500).send({
                                error: 'Error signing token',
                                raw: err,
                            });
                        }
                        res.send({
                            success: true,
                            token: `Bearer ${token}`,
                            email: user.email,
                        });
                    });



                } else {
                    errors.password = 'Password is incorrect';
                    res.status(400).json(errors);
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
```

Но я не совсем, понимаю как мне это совместить с фейсбуком, 
как мне организовать правильно роуты если человек залогинился с facebook, мне нужно сформировать токен и его отправить на клиент, на клиенте я собираюсь записать его в localstorage

```
module.exports = (app, passport) => {
    app.get('/login/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: 'email', session: false}));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    app.get('/login/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
            failureRedirect: '/',
            session: false
        })
    );
};
```